# Calling a function twice in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function let's call it getX that takes four parameters which are a counter, a list of user, a variable x and the response. I want to do something like the following .

```
let detectX = function(i, users, x, res){
    if(i<users.length){
        //do something with x
        if(users.indexOf(x)){
            //do something
        } else{
            detectX(i, users, 0, res);
        }
        detectX(++i, users, x, res);
    }
    else{
        res.send({x})
    }
}
```

Of course this code won't work as I will be sending response twice from each function call

Is there anyway I could make these two function calls in one?

Comment: I don't understand which two functions you want to call twice.

Comment: First, `users.indexOf(x)` is incomplete. Use `users.indexOf(x) >= 0`. Second, for 2 function calls, you can use a local variable to hold necessary value

Comment: in case `x` is not in `users`, that's true that `detectX` will be called twice. But  it's unclear what you want to do anyway...

Comment: Is your problem that you are recursively calling `detectX` and not returning immediately, meaning the second recursive invocation will always be called when the stack is unwound?

Comment: detectX(++i, users, x, res); gets called every time after the if/else so eventually res.send() is called twice,are you sure this is the behavior you want?don't you need to remove that line?

Comment: Perhaps refactoring to a for loop might make it easier to grok?

Comment: and op should make the function "detectX" return x,so whoever is calling that should instead do res.send(detectX(a,b,c))

Comment: @Slavik I wanted to call detectX function in the else part and also after the if condition; meaning if x is not in users i want to call the function and also I want to call the function every time regardless of the result of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, if you wish to avoid multiple calls:

**Pointers**

- `indexOf` returns numeric value. `-1` if not found and index if found. Using `if(users.indexOf(x))` is not correct as it will fail if `x` is found as first element and if not value is found.
- If you wish to avoid multiple calls to same function, you can create local variables representing arguments and process them based on condition and finally pass them to single function call.

```js
let detectX = function(i, users, x, res){
    if(i<users.length){
      // Assign default values to them to avoid `else` processing
      let n = i,
          newX = 0;
        //do something with x
        if(users.indexOf(x) >= 0){
            //do something
            n++;
            newX = x;
        } 
        detectX(n, users, newX, res);
    }
    else{
        res.send({x})
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** This answer addresses just code refactoring to multiple calls to `directX`. If there is anything missing or incorrect, please comment along with your vote.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly,your res.send gets called twice, but that's not because you invoke detectX more than once in your function,but because your inner if/else is wrong..if you enter the else then you also call the second detectX so you should separate the 2 calls completely

```
 if(users.indexOf(x)){
    detectX(++i, users, x, res);//or whatever you have to do
 } else{
    detectX(i, users, 0, res);
 }
```

if i may point out one more thing,i'd refactor the function so it returns x and then send x in the response,something like this

```
let detectX = function(i, users, x){
    if(i<users.length){
        //do something with x
        if(users.indexOf(x)){
            return detectX(++i, users, x);
        } else{
            return detectX(i, users, 0);
        }

   }
   else{
       return x
   }
}

let detected = detectX(i,users,x)
res.send({detected})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let detectX = function(i, users, x, res){ 
    if(i<users.length){ 
    //do something with x        
    if(users.indexOf(x)){
     //do something 
    } else{ 
       detectX(i, users, 0, res); 
       return; // here
    } detectX(++i, users, x, res);
  } else{ 
   res.send({x})
  }
 }
```

I guess this is what you are looking for. Added a return statement after  the self call in else block.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve this problem by defining a global array and I named it functionsStack and I pushed one of the functions in it till I finish the loop

```
global.functionsStack = []

let detectX = function(i, users, x, res){
    if(i<users.length){
        //do something with x
        if(users.indexOf(x)){
            //do something
        } else{
            functionsStack.push({"i":i, "users":users, x:"0"});
        }
        detectX(++i, users, x, res);
    }
    else{
        if(functionsStack.length>0){
            var currentFunction = functionsStack[0];
            functionsStack.splice(0,1);
            detectX(currentFunction.i, currentFunction.users, currentFunction.x, res);
        } else{
            res.send({x});
        }
    }
}
```